# What tool should I use for collecting data from an web site

Tags: java, selenium

I want to write a code for parsing HTML from a site with announcements. I wish I could use Jsoup, but it's a bit complicated for getting the phone number from this site. I should click on a div first, then it is shown in the HTML code.

So, what tool should I use to perform click on elements and the parse the HTML ?

Selenium I think is not an option for me, because this code will run on a Java Server.

Comment: Java is actually a great choice for Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

If your usecase is to *parsing HTML from a site* [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) is one of the best tool. You won't even need [jsoup](/questions/tagged/jsoup).

To perform `click()`, `sendKeys()`, etc, irrespective of the server type, e.g. *Java Server*, [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) works just perfect while interacting with the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).